# App runs on Head Node but not on Compute Node through HPC Pack Job Manager

Tags: azure, cluster-computing, hpc

I am testing running tasks through the HPC Pack Job Manager but it always fails:

> task failed with exit code 1073741515

and the output is empty so no details are available.

Then I tried running simple codes. I started with this:

```
#include <fstream> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;
    int y, x = 10;;
    fin.open("number.txt");
    fout.open("output.txt");
    fout << "x * y = " << x*y << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and I thought maybe reading from files is the issue so let me try this:

```
int main()
{
    int x; 
    x = 9;
    return 0;
}
```

In my cluster I can only connect to the head node.

Please note that running any of my applications through cmd works perfectly in the head node and on the compute node (by running cmd in the network shared folder)

I tried putting my program file in a folder in c drive that I shared with HPCJobAdministrators, HPCJobOperators, HPCUsers and HPCAdminMirror. I also tried putting it in a compute node network shared folder. Still getting the same error.